# Литература для изучения CSS

Tags: html, css, книги

Посоветуйте список литературы и веб-ресурсов для изучения CSS?

Comment: @VladSpirin Я не уверен, что стоит дубликатить книги по CSS в книги по Html+Css. Здесь много книг - там их нет, кто будет перетаскивать,  закрывать? Если уж хотелось связать ссылками - то можно было просто в комментариях оставить ссылку.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Comment: @VladSpirin Я пока пишут ответ в ваш вопрос на мете, но мы можем паралельно и в чате побеседовать. [Го](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что уже есть в списке литературы основной вопрос про книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML/CSS

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924441/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-html-%d0%b8-css)

Comment: @L.F.C., в данном случае, вероятно, стоило закрывать как дубликат, т.е. с указанием конкретной ссылки на вопрос, а не общего упоминания, что, мол, есть уже в списке подходящий вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в последний раз когда я поднимал данный вопрос, никто за это даже браться не хотел, а по поводу моего вопроса про дубликаты, так мне ответили, что не надо вязать старье к новому чистому вопросу, ну и т. д.

Comment: @L.F.C. «не надо вязать старье к новому чистому вопросу» — это где обсуждалось?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в комментариях под одним из таких вопросов, и было это примерно 2-3 месяца назад. Дубликатить так дубликатить, я за.

Comment: @L.F.C., т.е., обсуждения не было, а просто кто-то высказал своё мнение. к тому же, как мне представляется, не совсем верное (впрочем, я не знаю контекста). мне кажется, имеет смысл узнать коллективное мнение по этому поводу. задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос на [meta].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вопрос есть по поводу литературы по вёрстке, я задавал ранее. Я не буду ещё вопрос поднимать, хочешь поднимай, я далее буду дубликатить тогда. Но тут тогда другой вопрос, а что с закрытыми уже делать? Тут модераторы должны будут по-шаманить, моих сил уж точно не хватет. Репутация пока что low

Comment: @L.F.C., 1. я не уверен, что даже модераторы могут изменить причину закрытия. 2. если вопрос уже закрыт, можно комментарий добавить, типа «дубликат: ссылка». тогда эта ссылка, по идее, должна появиться справа в списке «связанные вопросы».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin если ты внимательно глянешь на все вопросы имеющиеся по HTML/CSS литературе на SO, я их всех связал давно про что написал в вопросе на Мета. После моих деяний с данными списками литературы, желающий что-то менять не нашлось. Ты первый.

Comment: @L.F.C., я не предлагал «что-то менять». я предложил в *подобных случаях* (безотносительно того, касается ли вопрос литературы, или ещё каких-нибудь там html-ов/css-ов) закрывать вопрос с причиной «дубликат». это всё.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ок, как и писал выше, согласен и так буду далее делать, без всяких претензий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Большая книга CSS, Дэвид Макфарланд
- CSS. 100 и 1 совет, Эндрю Рэйчел
- CSS. Каскадные таблицы стилей, Эрик Мейер
- CSS. Рецепты программирования, Кристофер Шмитт
- CSS ручной работы, Дэн Седерхольм

Это все на Озоне есть.

А еще [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/) - чтобы быть в курсе всех модных новинок. Благо IE9 уже вышел, и скоро HTML5 начнет свое победное шествие по сети.

Answer (score 3):

1. [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru)
2. Рейчел Эндрю - "CSS. 100 и 1 совет"
3. Эрик А. Мейер - "CSS. Каскадные таблицы стилей. Подробное руководство"

Answer (score 2):

Есть хороший сайт [zvirec.com](http://zvirec.com). Там все очень подробно и хорошо изложено. Потом можно посмотреть [интернет университет информационных технологий](http://intuit.ru). В общем для нормального начала работы хватит и сайта zvirec. А потом уже будете просто дополнять свои знания.

Comment: Полностью согласен. По книгам учится очень долго. Их можно использовать в дальнейшем для пополнения своих знаний. А Звирек действительно отличный сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошая книга на сайте websovet.com, там как раз для таких как мы, которые что-то когда-то учили и решили освежиться =) http://css.manual.ru/ - тут вы найдете подробное объяснение всем правилам в CSS. Удачи. =)