# Вопросы в изучении CSS и каркасов сайта

Tags: html, css

какой этап обучения посоветуете знаю css html как насчёт более продвинутого типа фреймворки less sass мексины и другое

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Литература для изучения CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/8516/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-css)

Comment: Там все ответы от 2011 года.

Comment: @MikhailSibirev это было в 2011 году прошло 6 лет я думаю очень много что изменилось

Comment: Я об этом и говорю комментатору @Qwertiy )

Comment: @MikhailSibirev, ok, давай новый список составим?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я бы с радостью, но в данном вопросе некомпетентен. ) Сам бы с удовольствием посмотрел на свежий список.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 1):

Нужно начать изучать css/js фреймворки, там ты узнаешь много нового и узнаешь как лучше реализовать тот или иной функционал в т.ч. адаптив.
Вот небольшой список фреймворков:

1. Bootstrap 3 (http://getbootstrap.com) - советую начать с него
2. Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com)
3. Semantic UI (https://semantic-ui.com)