# Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS

Tags: html, css, книги

Рекомендуемая литература, документация, учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS

Формат:

> Имя Фамилия — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ г..

Формат для переведенной литературы:

> Имя Фамилия (Name Surname) — «Название книги целиком и полностью», ГГГГ перевода ("Full name of the book", YYYY )

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте этот.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям (когда они будут).
- Сохраняйте алфавитную (лексикографическую) сортировку по названию книги.
- Пожалуйста,

  - [не добавляйте сюда видеолекции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/262779) **и интерактивные курсы**,
  - не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент вроде торрент-трекеров.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Литература (HTML):

- Брюс Лоусон, Реми Шарп - “Изучаем HTML5. Библиотека специалиста”, Питер, 2012, 304 стр. (ориг. название: "Introducing HTML5 ", New Riders)
- Кристофер Шмитт, Кайл Симпсон - "HTML5: Рецепты программирования", Питер, 2012, 288 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML5 Cookbook", O'Reilly)
- Эстель Вейл - "HTML5: Разработка приложений для мобильных устройств", 2015, 480 стр. (ориг. название: "Mobile HTML5", O'Reilly)
- Дженнифер Нидерст Роббинс - "HTML5. Карманный справочник", Вильямс, 2016, 192 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML5: Pocket Reference", O'Reilly)
- Джон Дакетт - "HTML и CSS. Разработка и дизайн веб-сайтов", Эксмо, 2017, 480 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML и CSS: Design and Build Websites", John Wiley & Sons)
- Крис Минник, Эд Титтел - "HTML5 и CSS3 для чайников ", Диалектика, 2016, 400 стр. (ориг. название: "Beginning HTML5 and CSS3 For Dummies", John Wiley & Sons)
- А. Хрусталев, А. Кириченко "HTMLS + CSS3. Основы современного WEB-дизайна", Наука и Техника, 2018, 352 стр.
- Бен Фрейн (Ben Frain) - "HTML5 и CSS3. Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств", Питер, 2017, 272 стр. (ориг. название: "Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3", Packt Publishing)

## Литература (CSS):

- Лия Веру - "Секреты CSS. Идеальные решения ежедневных задач", Питер, 2017, 336 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS Secrets. Better solutions to everyday web design problems", O'Reilly)
- Дэвид Макфарланд - "Новая большая книга CSS", Питер, 2016, 720 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS The missing manual", O'Reilly)
- Эрик А. Майер - "CSS. Карманный справочник",
  Вильямс, 2017, 288 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS Pocket Reference", O'Reilly)
- Кит Грант - "CSS для профи", Питер, 2019, 496 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS in Depth", Manning)

## Онлайн-справочники и pесурсы для обучения:

- [Doka](https://doka.guide/)
- [WebReference](https://webref.ru/)
- [Metanit](https://metanit.com/web/html5/)
- [html5book](https://html5book.ru/)
- [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/)
- [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)
- [W3C. HTML 5](https://w3c.github.io/html/)
- [W3C. Cascading Style Sheets home page](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)
- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)