# С чего начать изучение Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как новичку начать изучение Javascript, посоветуйте лучшие источники.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474385/262779)

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924441/262779)

Comment: @InDevX дубликат на дубликат.

Comment: @doox911 сознательно. По сути то что вы "оригиналом" назвали не является вопросом, это целенаправленно созданный ресурс, у которого не может быть дубликата (сугубо моё мнение)

Answer (score 0):

Буквально вчера советовал в другом вопросе.

http://code.mu/tasks/javascript/base/osnovy-yazyka-javascript-dlya-novichkov.html - тут есть как практика, так и теория, и все довольно хорошо структурировано.

Comment: Благодарю. А Вы имеете опыт в работе на Джаваскрипте?

Comment: Да, я работаю front-end разработчиком в крупной компании.

Comment: Вы где то учились? Я просто тоже начинающий фронт. Мне интересно, как сейчас в эту область попасть. Все постоянно совершенствуется и меняется. Такое ощущение, что невозможно угнаться.

Comment: Нет, сам. по гайдам и урокам в интернете, но это было очень давно. Сначала фрилансил, потом повезло попасть в небольшую компанию с большим потоком небольших задач. А потом уже в крупную. Важно  знать основы и попасть в русло где программировать нужно каждый день, остальное приходит по мере работы.