# Хорошие бесплатние курсы по html и css

Tags: css, html5

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, ресурсами с актуальной информацией по `html` и `css`.

Comment: Кхм, вы меня простите, но это наглость. Вы не умеете Гуглом пользоваться?!

Comment: А ещё есть ютуб :D, там вообще всё показывает прямо на видео куда тыкают

Answer (score 2):

У нас на сайте есть [хорошая подборка литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924447/28748) по HTML и CSS

Если найдёте, что-то стоящее, которое не вошло в список ниже, пожалуйста добавьте источник в указанный выше топик

**Литература (HTML):**

- Брюс Лоусон, Реми Шарп - “Изучаем HTML5. Библиотека специалиста”, Питер, 2012, 304 стр. (ориг. название: "Introducing HTML5 ", New Riders)
- Кристофер Шмитт, Кайл Симпсон - "HTML5: Рецепты программирования", Питер, 2012, 288 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML5 Cookbook", O'Reilly)
- Эстель Вейл - "HTML5: Разработка приложений для мобильных устройств", 2015, 480 стр. (ориг. название: "Mobile HTML5", O'Reilly)
- Дженнифер Нидерст Роббинс - "HTML5. Карманный справочник", Вильямс, 2016, 192 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML5: Pocket Reference", O'Reilly)
- Джон Дакетт - "HTML и CSS. Разработка и дизайн веб-сайтов", Эксмо, 2017, 480 стр. (ориг. название: "HTML и CSS: Design and Build Websites", John Wiley & Sons)
- Крис Минник, Эд Титтел - "HTML5 и CSS3 для чайников ", Диалектика, 2016, 400 стр. (ориг. название: "Beginning HTML5 and CSS3 For Dummies", John Wiley & Sons)
- А. Хрусталев, А. Кириченко "HTMLS + CSS3. Основы современного WEB-дизайна", Наука и Техника, 2018, 352 стр.
- Бен Фрейн (Ben Frain) - "HTML5 и CSS3. Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств", Питер, 2017, 272 стр. (ориг. название: "Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3", Packt Publishing)

**Литература (CSS):**

- Лия Веру - "Секреты CSS. Идеальные решения ежедневных задач", Питер, 2017, 336 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS Secrets. Better solutions to everyday web design problems", O'Reilly)
- Дэвид Макфарланд - "Новая большая книга CSS", Питер, 2016, 720 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS The missing manual", O'Reilly)
- Эрик А. Майер - "CSS. Карманный справочник",
  Вильямс, 2017, 288 стр. (ориг. название: "CSS Pocket Reference", O'Reilly)

---

**Онлайн-справочники и pесурсы для обучения:**

[WebReference](https://webref.ru/)
[Metanit](https://metanit.com/web/html5/)
[html5book](https://html5book.ru/)
[htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/)
[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org)
[W3C. HTML 5](https://w3c.github.io/html/)
[W3C. Cascading Style Sheets home page](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)