# Не получается отправить формы

Tags: django, tilda

Вообщем решил заняться сайтом долго не заморачиваясь, решил я скопировать сайт через сервис. Скопировал сайт zip архивом, как оказалось сайт копируется через тильду. Вообщем закинул я это все добро в django, к формам прикрутил js скрип на отправку заявки в телеграмм, ввожу команду runserver перехожу на 8000 порт, заполняю формы, нажимаю отправить , а мне на : Отправка данных невозможна. Укажите в настройках сайта действующее имя домена, с которого будет осуществляться отправка форм. Или же к форме не подключен приемщик или был удален. Домен с которого были отправлены данные: 127.0.0.1:8000 . Сделал form django {{}} в html и все тот же ответ.

Comment: «я в этом деле не профи» — тогда вам сюда: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924441)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в head удалить скрипт отвечающий за отправку формы через tilda

```
<script src="https://static.tildacdn.com/js/tilda-forms-1.0.min.js" charset="utf-8" async onerror="this.loaderr='y';"></script>
```